# Replace $\sum$ with $\ln$

Tags: summation

Reading an solution I get stuck at this step.

$$ 
\frac{1}{2i} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n} \left( e^{2in} - e^{-2in} \right) \\
= - \frac{1}{2i} \left( \ln(1 + e^{2i}) - \ln(1- e^{-2i}) \right) 
$$

Could someone explain to me what is done here? How can $\sum$ be replace with $\ln$? What is really done here? Is it possible to  divide this into more steps?

Comment: $$\forall |z|<1 : -\ln(1+z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}z^n$$

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: It's a Taylor series expansion.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\ln (1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{n}}{n} $$

Where $x\in (-1,1]$

Comment: this is not different from what ethan has written in his comments.... please consider editing this..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: I've edited it.

Comment: What have you edited? It looks same.